# Is using one's own initials as an identifier for a translation allowed?

Tags: discussion

Please see this answer and my comment below it:

[In James 2:7, what is the meaning of the phrase «τὸ ἐπικληθὲν ἐφ᾽ ὑμᾶς»?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/in-james-27-what-is-the-meaning-of-the-phrase-%cf%84%e1%bd%b8-%e1%bc%90%cf%80%ce%b9%ce%ba%ce%bb%ce%b7%ce%b8%e1%bd%b2%ce%bd-%e1%bc%90%cf%86%e1%be%bd-%e1%bd%91%ce%bc%e1%be%b6%cf%82/25970?s=1|444.4609#25970)

Answer (score 7):

Allowed?

I'm not sure that's the right question. There are a very limited number of things we actually flat out don't allow. Maybe "encourage" might be a better question.

Encouraged?

**No.**

We have, in fact, so strongly discouraged this that the initials (which used to be in every answer that user posted are now [nowhere to be found](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=epv). We helped him systematically go through and edit all his posts to say clearly "I would translate like this" or something to that effect. This is a complete turn around from his initial posts which distanced himself from the citations.

In this case his personal translation is "published" in the sense that it is online and there labeled under that set of initial. So strictly speaking we probably couldn't say "you are not allowed", but given the one-man nature of the translation and that it is the same author as the posts we thought it was much better to have him say clearly every time that it was his own translation.

The only thing left where "EPV" appears is in [screenshots](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:hermeneutics.stackexchange.com%20epv&tbm=isch), and it would hardly be reasonable to edit those out.

While he is of course allowed to used his own translation and he does show his work, I've noticed a pretty serious corelation in how well his answered are received based on how dependent they are on his own translation. When he can answer and demonstrate the point from a widely recognized translation they stand a fighting chance. When his point is dependent on his own (often highly) idiosyncratic translation the tend to fall pretty flat.

Feel free to vote on the merit of the hermeneutics on display. Don't worry too much abut the use of silly initials. Whatever the case may be for his own site and hence the screen shots, at least in post he does identify his work.